# Position a block on product page below tabs - Magento

Tags: php, xml, zend-framework, magento

I am working on Magento CE 1.6.2 and have an extension installed which display 'Other Customers also Bought' which displays fine exactly below the tabs.

Now I would like to position 'Recently viewed products' on Product page right at the bottom, just before the footer.

So I want some thing like this

```
      Tabs
      'other customers also bought'
      'Recently Viewed products'
  Footer Starts here...
```

But for some reason my 'Other Customers also bought' is getting over lapped with 'Recently Viewed Products'

I tried changing the layout files but to no success

Layout file for other customers also bought otherbought.xml

```
   <catalog_product_view>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="relatedproducts/relatedproducts" name="catalog.product.awrelated.community" as="othersbought_products" after="info_tabs" template="catalog/product/list/awrelated.phtml">
            <action method="setTarget">
                <alias>community</alias>
            </action>                   
        </block>    
    </reference>        
</catalog_product_view>
```

Layout for Recently Viewed Products reports.xml

```
    <catalog_product_view translate="label">
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="reports/product_viewed" name="right.reports.product.viewed" as="recently_viewed" template="reports/product_viewed.phtml" />
    </reference>
</catalog_product_view>
```

And for tabs i'm using EasyTabs extension, easytabs.xml

```
  <reference name="product.info.additional">
            <action method="unsetChild" ifconfig="easy_tabs/general/tagstabbed"><name>product_tag_list</name></action>
            <block type="catalog/product_view_tabs" name="product.info.tabs" as="info_tabs">
                <action method="setTemplate" ifconfig="easy_tabs/general/enabled"><template>easytabs/tabs.phtml</template></action>
                <action method="addTab" translate="title" module="catalog" ifconfig="easy_tabs/general/descriptiontabbed"><alias>description_tabbed</alias><title>Description</title><block>catalog/product_view_description</block><template>easytabs/description.phtml</template></action>
                </block>
    </reference>
```

I guess a `before` or `after` element can be used but its not working. Or If there is any way to directly show 'Recently Viewed Products' right at the bottom of product page just before the footer ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I commented reports.xml and took the  line from that file putting it into 'othersbought.xml'. So now my othersbought.xml file looks like this :

```
   <catalog_product_view>
   <reference name="content">
    <block type="relatedproducts/relatedproducts" name="catalog.product.awrelated.community" as="othersbought_products" after="info_tabs" template="catalog/product/list/awrelated.phtml">
        <action method="setTarget">
            <alias>community</alias>
        </action>                   
    </block> 
   <!-- Added Recently viewed products here below 'Others Bought' block --->   
   <block type="reports/product_viewed" name="right.reports.product.viewed" as="recently_viewed" template="reports/product_viewed.phtml" />
   <!-- ************ -->
   </reference>        
   </catalog_product_view>
```

This makes the 'Recently Viewed products' block to appear exactly below 'Other also bought' block which is what I had wanted.

May be not the most right way to do it, but works for me for now.

Answer (score 0):

The position in the `content` area is not controlled using the `before` and `after` tags, but is determined by where they are positioned in `view.phtml` or the files that control the blocks in that such as `tabs.phtml`.

Try looking for things of this form:

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('addtocart') ?>
```

Which indicate a block defined in a layout with name `addtocart` is being called.

If you want to know which template file controls which part you can try turning on `Template Path Hints` in the `System->Configuration->Developer` (admin panel), and then visit the page. Obviously not on a live site! Note you can't do this for the default configuration, so you need to choose a store view.

Comment: I did try to give a name by using `as` property in layout files and then declaring it in view.phtml file as `getChildHtml('othersbought')` and `getChildHtml('recently_viewed')` but it doesnt work in that order. It gets displayed regardless of its order once declared in layout files.

Comment: The order in the layout files has no bearing. Have you checked the generated source to see if the visual order matches the underlying order? In case it is a css issue.